# Tensorflow NN not giving any reasonable output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to train a network on the isolet dataset, consisting of 6238 samples with 300 features each.

This is my code so far:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sklearn.preprocessing as prep

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():
    X, C, Xtst, Ctst = load_isolet()

    #normalize 
    #X = (X - np.mean(X, axis = 1)[:, np.newaxis]) / np.std(X, axis = 1)[:, np.newaxis]
    #Xtst = (Xtst - np.mean(Xtst, axis = 1)[:, np.newaxis]) / np.std(Xtst, axis = 1)[:, np.newaxis]

    scaler = prep.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
    scaledX = scaler.fit_transform(X)
    scaledXtst = scaler.transform(Xtst)

    # Build the tf.keras.Sequential model by stacking layers. Choose an optimizer and loss function for training:
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(X.shape[1], activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(26, activation='softmax')
    ])

    ES_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', min_delta=1e-2, patience=10, verbose=1)
    initial_learning_rate = 0.01
    lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(initial_learning_rate,decay_steps=100000,decay_rate=0.9999,staircase=True)
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = model.fit(scaledX, C, epochs=100, callbacks=[ES_callback], batch_size = 32)

    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(range(len(history.history['loss'])), history.history['loss']);
    plt.plot(range(len(history.history['accuracy'])), history.history['accuracy']);
    plt.show()
```

Up to now, I have pretty much turned every knob I know:

- different number of layers
- different sizes of layers
- different activation functions
- different learning rates
- different optimizers (we should test with 'adam' and 'stochastic gradient decent'
- different batch sizes
- different data preparations (the features range from -1 to 1 values. I tried normalizing along the feature axes, batch normalizing (z_i = (x_i - mean) / std(x_i)) and as seen in the code above scaling the values from 0 to 1 (since I guess 'relu' activation won't work well with negative input values)

Pretty much everything I tried gives weird outputs with extremely high loss values (depending on the learning rate) and very low accuracies during learning. The loss is increasing over epochs pretty much all of the time, but seems to be independent from the accuracy values.

For the code, I followed tutorials I got provided, however something is very off, since I should find the best hyper parameters, but I'm not able to find any good whatsoever.

I'd be very glad to get some points, where got the code wrong or need to preprocess the data differently.

Edit: Using `loss='categorical_crossentropy'`was given, so at least this one should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all:

Your convergence problems may be due to "incorrect" loss function. `tf.keras` supports a variety of losses that depend on the shape of your input labels.
Try different possibilities like 
`tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` if your labels are [one-hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) vectors.
`tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy` if your lables are 1,2,3...
or `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy` if your labels are just 0,1.

Honestly, this part of `tf.keras` is a bit tricky and some settings like that might need tuning.

Second of all - this part:

```
    scaler = prep.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
    scaledX = scaler.fit_transform(X)
    scaledXtst = scaler.fit_transform(Xtst)
```

assuming `Xtst` is your test set you want to scale it based on your training set. So the correct scaling would be just

```
scaledXtst = scaler.transform(Xtst)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx for the answer. The loss function should be OK, it was provided by my tutor for this assignment. Problem is, I don't even use the Testset for evaluation right now, since I don't even get good values on the training set during training...

Comment: OK, I'm marking this as answer, since the following was the case: Labels `C` where given as Integers, but should encoded as "one-out-of-K" (which I understand as one-hot). The labels represent one out of the 26 labels of the alphabet. I have transformed C now from an array of integers into arrays of one-hot vectors based on the original integers and get much better results.